# Firebird connection string not working post Firebird 3 migration

Tags: firebird, firebird-3.0, firebird-.net-provider

I have a regression with a TCP\IP connection string post a firebird 3 migration from v2.5. The FirebirdClient version is 4.6.1 but I've tested with the latest stable version and it also doesn't work (v7.10.1).

The error message is "Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login".

The stacktrace:

```
at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPoolManager.Pool.GetConnection(FbConnection owner)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionPoolManager.Get(ConnectionString connectionString, FbConnection owner)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection.Open()
```

The user was created via the IBExpert UI.

Here's how the connection string looks (not real life connection data obviously):

```
@"Database=inet://10.000.0.000:3050/C:\Database.FDB;User=MY_USER;Password=secret";
```

The same user works if using a standard same network connection string as below:

```
@dialect=3;initial catalog=C:\Database.FDB;data source=localhost;user id=MY_USER;password=secret;character set=ISO8859_1;pooling=True;connection lifetime=30;server type=Default;port number=3050
```

My firebird.conf is set like so:

```
ServerMode = Super
DefaultDbCachePages = 100K
FileSystemCacheThreshold = 100M
TempBlockSize = 2M
TempCacheLimit = 4000M
AuthServer = Legacy_Auth, Srp, Win_Sspi
AuthClient = Legacy_Auth, Srp, Win_Sspi
UserManager = Legacy_UserManager, Srp
WireCrypt = Enabled 
RemoteServicePort = 3050
LockMemSize = 30M
LockHashSlots = 30011
RemoteAccess = true
```

Not sure what I'm missing here. The connection string above works with SYSDBA. According to the firebird documentation I've read it looks fine. I've read all other stackoverflow tickets with the same issue but don't see any answers that work for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient support the version 13-15 wire protocol of Firebird 3, and then only support Srp authentication. Your old version supported only up to the v12 protocol (Firebird 2.5) and then would use the legacy authentication. If you created the user using the Legacy_UserManager (the default in your configuration), then you cannot authenticate with version 7.10.1 (where you could with 4.6.1), because as far as the Srp authentication plugin is concerned, the user does not exist.

It looks like you created the user either using *gsec*, which always applies the default user manager (FYI, *gsec* is deprecated since Firebird 3), or you used [`CREATE USER`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-security-user-create) without `USING PLUGIN Srp` (or with `USING PLUGIN Legacy_UserManager`). You can verify this by checking the output of `select sec$user_name, sec$plugin from sec$users`. The solution would be to drop the user and then create it again with the right user manager (`USING PLUGIN Srp`).

Note that in theory you could have the user both for Srp and Legacy_UserManager (e.g. if the same user needs to be used by an application that cannot authenticate with Srp), but it is far more secure to have the user only exist for one plugin.

On a related note, the configuration you have applied is insecure. It is far more secure to leave out `Legacy_Auth` of the `AuthServer` setting or - if you still have applications that cannot apply Srp - to put it **last** (for both `AuthServer` and `AuthClient`). Similarly, it is recommended to put `Legacy_UserManager` last in `UserManager` (or leave it out entirely), so by default - if you use *gsec*, or don't include `USING PLUGIN xxx` in `CREATE USER` - it will create more secure Srp-type users.

Comment: Thanks Mark, dropping the user and re-adding using Srp did the trick. The other information you provided was also most useful. Thank you!